# 403 error on htaccess url routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-403

I am new to URL Routing so this issue might be from something which I did wrong. I am using PHP and I need to have simple clean URLs without showing the .php extension in browser. So I used the routing engine from the fat free framework (f3) and added a .htaccess file to the root folder. I followed a tutorial on this and this is the content on my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework.php [L,QSA]
```

So i need to redirect all request to framework.php file if no physical file or directory is matched.

Everything was working fine with this, but I recently tried indexing with google and as it turns out robots get a 403 error when the url of the website is given.

For example www.abc.com works fine on browser but gets a 403 error in fetch as google tool. The error is occurring in google page speed insights as well.

When you try to access it as www.abc.com/benefits/ again it works fine on browser but get a 404 error in fetch as google tool.

My robots.txt file contains the following

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Allow: /
```

The error make sense if no URL routing is present because I do not have a index.php file and no physical sub directory called benefits. But since I have the rewrite rule I cant figure out why its giving the 403 and 404 errors and why only for robots.

Could any one tell me what’s I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: There does not appear to be anything in your .htaccess and robots.txt files that could result in a difference between robot and normal visitor traffic? Have you checked the HTTP status code in your browser - do you see a `200 OK` status? Is Google receiving a full 403/404 response, or are you just reporting the status code?

Comment: It says it received a 403 response from the server.

Comment: When I use a HTTP Header Status Checker tool it says Response: 403 Forbidden, but you get the website content in the respond body.

Comment: In that case it seems your site is returning the wrong HTTP status code for some reason (for everyone), despite apparently sending the correct response body. In the case of a 403/404, Google (and other search engines) will only pay attention to the all important HTTP status code.

Answer (score 1):

As w3d pointed out the problem is not only for the robots and there was nothing wrong with the htaccess file.

The problem was with my main controller which is framework.php

I renamed that to index.php and now the issue has been solved. For some reason even though the url and folder structure is virtual, the server is looking for a index file in the root folder.

Comment: "nothing wrong with the htaccess file" - actually, I think you probably could fix this with a change to your .htaccess file. The problem you were experiencing (the 403 at least) is consistent with `mod_dir` (`DirectoryIndex`) trying to auto-load the index document when you access a directory (including the root directory) - which doesn't exist in this case. Your .htaccess file specifically excludes requests for directories, so the request is not rewritten when a directory is specified! So, you could simply remove the directory check in .htaccess: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.

Comment: However, that doesn't quite explain the 404s and the fact that you appeared to get a valid response (ie. the correct page) in the browser, unless your framework is also processing 403s and managed to somehow route the request...?